# How can I extend the Set object in Snap

Tags: snap.svg

I am trying to convert a large body of code from Raphael to Snap.
I am coming across a number of problems - I will ask 1 question for each, to avoid thread confusion.

I have a number of calls to the Raphael toFront method. This method is missing from Snap, but I found a suggested implementation:

```
Snap.plugin(function (Snap, Element, Paper, glob) {
    var elproto = Element.prototype;
    elproto.toFront = function () {
        this.appendTo(this.paper);
        return this;
    };
    elproto.toBack = function () {
        this.prependTo(this.paper);
        return this;
    };
});
```

This is all very fine for Elements, but I find most of my toFront calls are on sets. Is there a way to extend the Snap set?

Comment: Have you looked into extending via prototype or something ?

Comment: The Set object seems to be declared inside a Snap.plugin function, so is not accessible to the outside world (as I understand it). Mind you the whole style of the Snap library (and many others) is a mystery to me, so I may be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same requirement, and managed to extend the `Set` via classic proptype as @Ian said.

```js
// example function (forEach reversed)
function revForEach(callback, thisArg)
{
    for (var i = this.items.length - 1, ii = 0; i >= ii; i--)
    {
        console.log(i);
        if (callback.call(thisArg, this.items[i], i) === false)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
    return this;
}

// extend Snap Set class
Snap.Set.prototype.revForEach= revForEach;
```